# Server Sent Event gives error in client but no error message

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I'm trying to get to grips with SSE with the help of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events.
Although everything works fine, I get an error on every server event. The error object doesn't contain the actual error (or I can't find it) but I'm not comfortable ignoring the error.

This is my client code (js):

```
const evtSource = new EventSource("http://ssedemo/server/ssedemo.php");
evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(event) {
    const newElement = document.createElement("li");
    const eventList = document.getElementById("list");

    newElement.innerHTML = "message: " + event.data;
    eventList.appendChild(newElement);
});

evtSource.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error("EventSource failed:", err);
};
```

And serverside (php) - abbreviated code from the example in the link

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
echo "event: ping\n";
echo 'data: This is a Ping at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";

ob_end_flush();
flush();
```

I see the events, everything works but in the console I get this error:

[image: screenshot of the error]

There's loads of info in there but I can't find the actual error.
Where should I look for the error? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Wellll... I switched to a Flask backend and sseclient, which works like a charm. In the frontend i now use a Vue package: vue-sse. This is one time I am actually glad to be using Flask. 
This article helped me greatly on my way: https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/flask-sse-no-deps/
The long living connection works way better using flask.